# CSS drop down explanation

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Could some one explain me how CSS drop downs works?

I've seen alot of them, most of them has the > selector,

My question is:

How can you make CSS dropdown with the > selector?

I looked towards a lot of tutorials and never understood what does the > do and how does it connects with the HTML classes\Ids.

Could someone explain me that, part by part?
Thank you.

Comment: @Jony Did you find any help with the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>        
        <span>menu 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >Sub 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Sub 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Sub 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>        
        <span>menu 2</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" >Sub 2-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Sub 2-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Sub 2-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul.menu>li{ /*Only direct children*/
    float:left;
    width: 60px;
}
ul.menu li ul{
    display:none; /*not visible*/
}

ul.menu li:hover ul{
    display:block; /* visible when hovering the parent li */
}
```

Explanation is in the css.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/FH7Z3/

Answer (score 6):

It is used to select direct children.

Consider following markup

```
<div id="container">  
   <ul>  
      <li> List Item  
        <ul>  
           <li> Child </li>  
        </ul>  
      </li>  
      <li> List Item </li>  
      <li> List Item </li>  
      <li> List Item </li>  
   </ul>  
</div>
```

A selector of `#container > ul` will only target the `uls` which are direct children of the `div` with an id of `container`.

It will not target, for instance, the `ul` that is a child of the first `li`.

For this reason, there are performance benefits in using the child combinator.

Comment: Oh I pretty muchg got it, but how do you make a menu pop up on hover & make it hide wehn you no longer hovering it?

Comment: @Jony Check Puyol's anwser he opens a sub menu on hover.There are so many tutorials for dropdown menus.I recommmend you searching google for this.

Comment: Yes, I posted this answer exactly when he posted his
Will do now ^^thank you

Answer (score 0):

The > operator in CSS means that following expression must be a direct child.

For example, `div span` matches SPAN elements which are descendants of a DIV element, but `div > span` only matches SPAN elements which are a direct child of a DIV.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

Answer (score 0):

see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) the `>` is a child selector. Rather than referencing to all the descendents we want to address only the direct descendents. View it as wanting to select only the children  but not grand children or any further.